# network namespace with veth bridge not working - ICMP sent but no reply

Tags: linux-networking, iproute2, network-namespace

I'm attempting to achieve a somewhat standard bridged netns setup with a veth pair, with one end in the ns and the other on the bridge :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0  -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

ip netns add sns
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev br0
ip link set br0 up 

ip link add veth0 type veth peer name br0-veth0 
ip link set br0-veth0 master br0
ip link set veth0 netns sns 
ip link set br0-veth0 up 

ip -n sns link set lo up
ip -n sns addr add 10.10.10.10/24 dev veth0
ip -n sns link set veth0 up
ip -n sns route add default via 10.10.10.1
```

I'm on a bit of an old version of ubuntu 18.04 linux 4.15.0-210-generic but I'd expect this to work! I've clear out iptables of all other rules and this arrangement works else where.

If I ping the outside world by IP `tcpdump` shows the ICMP request being sent out, but not returned:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 | grep ICMP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enxe8ea6a751298, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:05:32.434563 IP 10.10.10.2 > lhr25s34-in-f14.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 4160, seq 13, length 64
16:05:33.454709 IP 10.10.10.2 > lhr25s34-in-f14.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 4160, seq 14, length 64
16:05:34.478543 IP 10.10.10.2 > lhr25s34-in-f14.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 4160, seq 15, length 64
16:05:35.506559 IP 10.10.10.2 > lhr25s34-in-f14.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 4160, seq 16, length 64
16:05:36.526576 IP 10.10.10.2 > lhr25s34-in-f14.1e100.net: ICMP echo request, id 4160, seq 17, length 64
```

And there appears to be a return route :

```
ip route # ip route
default via [redacted ip] dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
10.10.10.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.1
```

Any clues / advice on how to diagnose further would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: This all works just fine for me (although you appear to be creating `br0` twice in your script). See a run-through [here](https://asciinema.org/a/vWKJLVLKMVvIGqRjIjfJ5NJKM).

Comment: "IP 10.10.10.2 > " is a private IP. Versus "default via [redacted ip]" I suspect there's something wrong about 10.10.10.2, but we can't know because "[redacted ip]" can't give a clue. If the route is via a public IP address, then 10.10.10.2 makes no sense (it's not visible anywhere in the setup): it should also be a public IP address, or you have a very strange setup or the obfuscation went wrong.

Comment: So: what's the result of `ip -4 -br addr show dev eth0`? More than one IP address on it? Use SNAT instead of MASQUERADE then.